# Elasticsearch Analysers give unexpected behaviour

Tags: elasticsearch

If I start off with my index created in this manner:

```
put newsindex
{
  "settings" : {
    "number_of_shards":3,
    "number_of_replicas":2,
    "analysis": {
 "filter": {
     "my_stop": {
         "type":      "stop",
        "stopwords":  "_english_"
     },
      "english_stemmer" : {
           "type": "stemmer",
           "language": "english"
     }
 },
    "analyzer" : {
      "english":  {
         "tokenizer" : "standard",
         "filter": [
            "my_stop",
            "english_stemmer"
       ]
     }
   }
        }
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "news": {
      "properties": {
        "newsid": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "newstype": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "bodytext": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "caption": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "headline": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "approved": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "author": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "contact": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "datecreated": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "date_time"
        },
        "datesubmitted": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "date_time"
        },
        "lastmodifieddate": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "date_time"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I then perform a search using the word '**scotland**', I have 158 documents returned. Looking at a number of them at random they all have this word somewhere in one of my search terms.

I now want my output to stop including 'stop' words on my search. i.e. as the above stands, if I search for '**is**', '**this**', '**that**' on their own I correctly get no records returned, however if I perform a search for **'is scotland**' I obtain thousands of documents because the search has now included documents that just have the word **is** in them, so the search seems to have dropped the stop words. So against the columns that I'm performing my search against I introduce the following:

```
 "analyzer": "english",
 "search_analyzer" : "english"
```

such that bodytext for instance becomes:

```
  "bodytext": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "english",
      "search_analyzer": "english"
```

but now if I perform the same search for '**scotland**' I only have 6 documents returned.

Just sticking with **Scotland** for the moment, this is the search built up.

```
"{ "query": { 
       "bool" : { "should" : [ 
                         { "wildcard" : { "headline" : { "value" : "*scotland*" }}}, 
                         { "wildcard": { "bodytext" : { "value" : "*scotland*" }}}]}},
        "_source" :["headline", "bodytext", "datesubmitted", "newsid"]}"
```

based on @Jpountz comment below, if I change **wildcard** to be **term** and remove the ***** from my query. I get all my documents returning as expected. if I change the value to **"is"** I also get every document with **is** in it. Stop words are now being ignored completely.

Comment: none of your columns use the analyzer you created to index, they are using the standard analyzer (text), you should set the analyzer you created on those columns so the indexing is done the same way as your searching is done.

Comment: @KinSlayerUY I have added the analyser to the mapping properties, this is when the query reduced to only returning 6 documents. Are you saying that I need to add the analyser to the query as well? if yes, can you show me how I should change my query to include the analyser at this level

Comment: Why do you use a wildcard query? Wildcard queries do not apply analyzers.

Comment: @jpountz Originally I didn't have any analysers declared just the stop filter.My original problem was as explained. if I queried on 'is', 'the' etc nothing returned (great), the issue was that if I then queried 'is scotland' the stop filter appeared to stop working as I also had returned any document with 'is' in it. I've now started to look at analysers, but this seems to make it worse. If analysers are what I should be using, but wildcard isn't the correct search, then what should I be using?

Comment: @bilpor no, the query should use the same analyzer as the field if none specified.

Comment: @KinSlayerUY, yes, on the query I haven't specified anything as you can see, so I don't understand why when applying the default analysers  on the mapping's when searching for 'Scotland' using the same query drop from 158 documents to only 6. without even thinking about the 'stop' words.